# Which mathematician first proved the laws of arithmetic?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

Specifically, the associative, distributive, and commutative laws of addition and multiplication.

Was it Peano?

Comment: Peano and Dedekind deduced them from arithmetical axioms, but prior "partial" proofs were already produced by Leibniz and [Grassmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, did Leibniz use the inductive principle?

Comment: NO, and he did not gave complete proof; e proved that e.g. $2+2=4$ and in this proof he relied on *associativity* (that he assumed). But the idea that we can prove "obvious" facts of elementary arithmetic "popped-up".

Comment: Which arithmetical axioms? Many axiomatizations of arithmetic take those laws as axioms. And if we are talking about Peano axioms specifically then of course it would have to be him. But it is dubious that Peano axioms are any more obvious than elementary laws of arithmetic, induction definitely seems less so, so his "proofs" are only meaningful within his particular formalization.

Comment: @Conifold,I disagree. The commutative law of multiplication isn't obvious at all imo and should be derivable from the basic definitions of summation and multiplication (which would be defined in terms of summation). One can do crude "intuitive proofs" say arranging items in a rectangular array, then saying no.rows x no. columns = no. columns x no. rows. But this isn't self-evident in a mathematical sense.

Comment: Euclid proves the commutativity of multiplication of whole numbers $> 1$ in [*Elements* VII 16](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVII/propVII16.html).

Comment: Interestingly, Euclid never proves or uses the associativity of multiplication, in keeping with his never using induction, by which associativity is proved by e.g. Dedekind.